# Capture and process video stream on mobile - where to start?

Tags: android, ios, video-streaming, video-capture, video-processing

I'm in the very beginning of a new project. Before diving into details need your advice on direction.

Requirements:

1. Get video stream from device's camera, render it as a preview and save for further processing
2. Do the same with external video stream (`http://...m3u8`)
3. Extract some frames from saved video, add some overlay, combine back to a playable video file and save locally and/or send to a server

Need to support iOS and Android devices.

Questions:

Q1. Is this all doable (and how hard) using only standard iOS/Android frameworks? Examples for #2 and #3? Keywords to google?

Q2. Is it better to bet on `ffmpeg` or something?

Q3. Will `Marmalade` or `MoSync` simplify `ffmpeg` compilation and use?

Q4. Any advice?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For Android  there is a NDK, try this
http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/ndk/docs/openmaxal/index.html

For iOS you can use default MPMoviewPlayer, for playing streams

```
      NSURL *mediaURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"];
      MPMoviePlayerController *mediaPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:mediaURL];
```

For custom tricks you need to use ffmpeg,
here is a script for compiling ffmpeg under iOS

```
export PLATFORM="iPhoneOS"
export MIN_VERSION="4.0"
export MAX_VERSION="5.0"
export DEVROOT=/Developer/Platforms/${PLATFORM}.platform/Developer
export SDKROOT=$DEVROOT/SDKs/${PLATFORM}${MAX_VERSION}.sdk
export CC=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/llvm-gcc
export LD=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ld
export CPP=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/cpp
export CXX=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/llvm-g++
export AR=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ar
export LIBTOOL=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/libtool
export NM=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/nm
export CXXCPP=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/cpp
export RANLIB=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ranlib
COMMONFLAGS="-pipe -gdwarf-2 -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot ${SDKROOT} -marm -fPIC"
export LDFLAGS="${COMMONFLAGS} -fPIC"
export CFLAGS="${COMMONFLAGS} -fvisibility=hidden"
export CXXFLAGS="${COMMONFLAGS} -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden"

FFMPEG_LIBS="libavcodec libavdevice libavformat libavutil libswscale"

echo "Building armv6..."

make clean
./configure \
    --cpu=arm1176jzf-s \
    --extra-cflags='-arch armv6 -miphoneos-version-min=${MIN_VERSION} -mthumb' \
    --extra-ldflags='-arch armv6 -miphoneos-version-min=${MIN_VERSION}' \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --arch=arm \
    --target-os=darwin \
    --cc=${CC} \
    --sysroot=${SDKROOT} \
    --prefix=installed \
    --disable-network \
    --disable-decoders \
    --disable-muxers \
    --disable-demuxers \
    --disable-devices \
    --disable-parsers \
    --disable-encoders \
    --disable-protocols \
    --disable-filters \
    --disable-bsfs \
    --enable-decoder=h264 \
    --enable-decoder=svq3 \
    --enable-gpl \
    --enable-pic \
    --disable-doc
perl -pi -e 's/HAVE_INLINE_ASM 1/HAVE_INLINE_ASM 0/' config.h
make -j3

mkdir -p build.armv6
for i in ${FFMPEG_LIBS}; do cp ./$i/$i.a ./build.armv6/; done

echo "Building armv7..."

make clean
./configure \
    --cpu=cortex-a8 \
    --extra-cflags='-arch armv7 -miphoneos-version-min=${MIN_VERSION} -mthumb' \
    --extra-ldflags='-arch armv7 -miphoneos-version-min=${MIN_VERSION}' \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --arch=arm \
    --target-os=darwin \
    --cc=${CC} \
    --sysroot=${SDKROOT} \
    --prefix=installed \
    --disable-network \
    --disable-decoders \
    --disable-muxers \
    --disable-demuxers \
    --disable-devices \
    --disable-parsers \
    --disable-encoders \
    --disable-protocols \
    --disable-filters \
    --disable-bsfs \
    --enable-decoder=h264 \
    --enable-decoder=svq3 \
    --enable-gpl \
    --enable-pic \
    --disable-doc
perl -pi -e 's/HAVE_INLINE_ASM 1/HAVE_INLINE_ASM 0/' config.h
make -j3

mkdir -p build.armv7
for i in ${FFMPEG_LIBS}; do cp ./$i/$i.a ./build.armv7/; done

mkdir -p build.universal
for i in ${FFMPEG_LIBS}; do lipo -create ./build.armv7/$i.a ./build.armv6/$i.a -output ./build.universal/$i.a; done

for i in ${FFMPEG_LIBS}; do cp ./build.universal/$i.a ./$i/$i.a; done

make install
```

use this for android ffmpeg
http://bambuser.com/opensource